# Adding previous(back) and next buttons next to the page numbers PHP

Tags: php, button, pagination, back

I have two tiny little problems;

1 . I want to add a previous / next button into this code
2 . I want it to only show like max 10 links between previous and next. So if i have 50 numbers/links it will only show 10 of them and not 50 links on the page.

I have searched on the clo

The code works, only need that two options in it.
Can someone help me out? Thank you !

```
 <?php 

        include 'includes/connection.php';  
        $per_page = 8;

        $pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `products`");
        $pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);

        $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
        $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;



        $query = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `products` LIMIT $start, $per_page");
        while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo '<p>', $query_row['name'] ,'</p>';
        }

        if ($pages >= 1 && $page <= $pages) {
            for ($x=1; $x<=$pages; $x++) { 
                //echo $x, ' '; 

                echo ($x == $page) ? '<strong><a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a></strong> ' : '<a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a> ';
            }
        }else{
            header("location:index.php?page=1");
        }


    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should, just for good practice, put an "exit;" after the header() call at the end. It doesn't make a difference in this particular script, but keep in mind that any code following a header("Location: ...") call WILL be executed before redirection.

Now to your question, try this (UPDATE: This code has been tested and works.)

```
<?php 
include 'includes/connection.php';  
$per_page = 8;
$pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `products`");
$pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);

$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

$query = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `products` LIMIT $start, $per_page");
while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo '<p>' . $query_row['name'] . '</p>';
}

// If the requested page is less than 1 or more than the total number of pages
// redirect to the first page
if($pages < 1 || $page > $pages)
{
    header('Location: ?page=1');
    // end execution of the rest of this script
    // it will restart execution after redirection
    exit;   
}
// If more than one page, show pagination links
if($pages > 1)
{
    $html = array();
    $html[] = '<strong>';
    // if you're on a page greater than 1, show a previous link
    $html[] = (($page > 1) ? '<a href="?page=' . ($page - 1) . '">Previous</a> ' : '');
    // First page link
    $pageFirst = '<a href="?page=1">1</a>';
    $html[] = (($page == 1) ? "</strong>{$pageFirst}<strong>" : $pageFirst);

    if ($pages > 6)
    {
        $start_cnt = min(max(1, $page - (6 - 1)), $pages - 6);
        $end_cnt = max(min($pages, $page + 4), 8);

        $html[] = ($start_cnt > 1) ? '...' : ' ';

        for ($i = $start_cnt + 1; $i < $end_cnt; $i++)
        {
            $html[] = ($i == $page) ? '</strong><a href="?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a><strong>' : '<a href="?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a>';
            if ($i < $end_cnt - 1)
            {
                $html[] = ' ';
            }
        }

        $html []= ($end_cnt < $pages) ? '...' : ' ';
    }
    else
    {
        $html[] = ' ';

        for ($i = 2; $i < $pages; $i++)
        {
            $html[] = ($i == $page) ? '</strong><a href="?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a><strong>' : '<a href="?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a>';
            if ($i < $pages)
            {
                $html[] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }
    // last page link
    $pageLast = '<a href="?page=' . $pages . '">' . $pages . '</a>';
    $html[] = (($page == $pages) ? "</strong>{$pageLast}<strong>" : $pageLast);
    // Show next page link if you're on a page less than the total number of pages
    $html[] = ($page < $pages) ? ' <a href="?page=' . ($page + 1) . '">Next</a>' : '';
    // If you're not on the last page, show a next link
    $html[] = '</strong>';
}
else
{
     // show page number 1, no link.
    $html[] = '<strong>1</strong>';
}
echo implode('', $html);
```

Also note that the final ?> is not required in PHP files that do not have HTML code following the PHP code, so I left it off.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Well on the page it shows: 1 2 1">Next and -1">Previous1 2

Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: Also.. Previous and Next are no links

Comment: I'm working on somewhat of a rewrite. will post what I have in a few

Comment: Here's what I've come up with, borrowing/adapting some code from phpBB's pagination system. The hard part wasn't the next/previous links, but rather getting it to only show 10 maximum at a time. http://pastebin.com/KEWMirzm -- btw I also updated the code in the answer

Comment: Wow! ! ! You are truly awesome! Thank you so much! It works!! :D

Comment: Hello again, sorry to bother you but I had a question.
If you am on the first page, I can't see the previous button, only next, but when I press next I see the previous button *logical* but could you tell me how to show previous even if I am on page one? But previous needs to be deactivated if I'm on page one.

Thank you,
F4LLCON

Comment: Here's the updated code: http://pastebin.com/2vcz30A6 EDIT: All I did was in the inline if statements where it has the links for the previous and next buttons was added the plain text "Previous" and "Next" (lines 31 and 71) so that it will display instead of the link when there is no previous or next page to display, respectively.

Comment: Thank you so much!
Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Buddy refer this URL

http://www.codediesel.com/php/simple-pagination-in-php/

OR

http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination

Surely will help you.

Thanks